# How to put <li> in a flexible structure?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a div with several ul and li inside. And the problem is they are very hard to get to fill up the space. Either they leave a big gap on the right side, or one on the uls gets pushed down below. I have to consider that different users have different sized screens.

I need to make the uls flexible, so that they will cover the space better no matter what size space it is. When the size of the window is reduced, I want the lis to adjust.

Is this possible? Any advice would be appreciated.

Ok, here is some code. You guys already gave me some ideas, let's see if the code can help:

```
<div style="max-width:100%">
       <ul style="list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">

        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            </ul>

       <ul style="list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

See, I want these to sit next to each other, but then there will be a gap, and if the screen changes, the gap gets worse...

I have got bootstrap in this page, but how to utilize?

Comment: Can't tell you anything for sure without some HTML to work off. But you're probably either after media queries. Edit your question with a sample of your HTML structure.

Comment: Don't use fixed width in your css like `10px` or `100px` use percent values like `10%` or `50%` etc. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Media queries or a grid system like bootstrap. If you use only percentages you'll most likely have overflow problems.

Comment: You mean something like that http://jsfiddle.net/5D77u/ ?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mbQ5P I want the uls to sit next to each other, but don't want them to react to the space improperly

Comment: I am going to make another post. Hope thats ok

Answer (score 1):

Well I got some assistance, thanks to all. I added the {width:25%} but for some reason they aren't all sitting in a line with each other, even though I have lowered everything to 20%, which should allow them to all be in a row...and I am wondering what will happen when the div gets smaller, maybe media queries are the way to go. But, for now, thanks to all.

Here is what I have so far:

And the jdfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbQ5P

```
 <div style="width:100%">
               <ul style="width:20%; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">

            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
                </ul>

           <ul style="width:20%; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
                </ul>
                           <ul style="width:20%; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">

            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
                </ul>
                           <ul style="width:20%; list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1">

            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
            <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: If you have width 25% and a float left (assuming you want rows of uls), then you'll get janky text when the page gets too small. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and look at the grid system. There are better alternatives like Susy, if you're using SASS/SCSS. Bootstrap is by far the easiest to understand and use though.

With a grid system you can define at certain view breakpoints how big you want something to be. For example you can fit 6 uls on a large desktop screen, 3 on a medium size screen and 1 on a mobile sized screen.

Comment: Ok I have bootstrap, and have learned how to use it to some extent.  Thanks for the direction.